# Webgl Circle without using extrernal library

Tags: webgl

I am new to webgl and at this point I am able to create a triangle and square.

I am finding it difficult to understand how to create a circle with out any external scripts or libraries.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to give us more than that. Can you edit your question to include what you have tried (code snippets, errors, etc.)

Comment: I actually created the circle,can you help me ,i want to generate upto 10 random circles along the circumference of the big circle.I have an idea to use the vertices generated but dont know how to access it.You can look at the answer i posted below

Comment: Don't use an answer to show us what you've tried. Answers are for solutions, not more parts of your question. Use Edit to modify the text of your question to show your code. I can't actually help you with your question, I'm just one of the moderators.

Comment: [Read some tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org)?

Answer (score -2):

```
    var vertexShaderText =
    [
    'uniform vec2 u_resolution;',
    '',
    'attribute vec2 a_position;',
    '',
    'void main()',
    '{',
    '',
    'vec2 clipspace = a_position / u_resolution * 1.0 ;',
    '',
    'gl_Position = vec4(clipspace * vec2(2.5, 2.0), 0, 1);',
    '}'
    ].join("\n");
    var fragmentShaderText =
    [
    'precision mediump float;',
    '',
    'void main(void)',
    '{',
    '',
    'gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1.0);',
    '',
    '}'

    ].join("\n");
var uni = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("game-surface");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    console.log("This is working");

    gl.clearColor(0.412,0.412,0.412,1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    var vertextShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertextShader,vertexShaderText);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);

    gl.compileShader(vertextShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertextShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error with vertexshader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertextShader));
        return;
    }
    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error with fragmentShader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        return;
    }



    var program =gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program,vertextShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error linking program",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        return;
    }
    gl.validateProgram(program);
    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error validating",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    }

    var circle = {x: 0, y:0, r: 75};
    var ATTRIBUTES = 2;
    var numFans = 64;
    var degreePerFan = (2* Math.PI) / numFans;
    var vertexData = [circle.x, circle.y];

    for(var i = 0; i <= numFans; i++) {
      var index = ATTRIBUTES * i + 2; // there is already 2 items in array
      var angle = degreePerFan * (i+0.1);
      vertexData[index] = circle.x + Math.cos(angle) * circle.r;
      vertexData[index + 1] = circle.y + Math.sin(angle) * circle.r;
    }

    var vertexDataTyped = new Float32Array(vertexData);

    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataTyped, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexData.length/ATTRIBUTES);




};
```

Comment: Pleas edit your question and add this code to it, and then remove this 'answer', as it is not a solution to your question.